# MVC2: Is rendering List<object> possible in Create context?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have this Model:

```
public class Package
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I add the Create's view, the code is:

```
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustomerName) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName) %>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

How manage the *Products* list?
Can I get a button or something to create a new product and add it to the *Products* list?

Thank you

Comment: Also, look into MvcScaffolding, it will generate all your controllers, models, and views. Quite flexible, mvcscaffolding.codeplex.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for creating buttn you can also do this use HTML.ActionLink() or Ajax.ActionLink() defined as a button like:

```
<% Response.Write(Html.ActionLink("Add Product", "Create", new { id = tId, tNum = tNum }, new { @class = "oldVal" })); %>
```

it'll create a button on your page, and here you can see different attributes (so just check them out you'll find it useful) ... and from both of this which to use is more depends upon your desired action ...

and in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Create() 
{
    // do same as mentioned by [gnome][1]
}
```

here is the example: modal popup, declared as a partial view of page
[partial view using Ajax.ActionLink()]

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Users", null, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "divLoginPopupContent" }))
            {
                Response.Write(Html.ValidationSummary(true));
    %>
                <ul class="chooseQuestion">
                    <li>
                        <div class="short">
                            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.LoginEmail)%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LoginEmail)%>
                            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LoginEmail)%>
                        </div>
                    </li><li>
                        <div class="short">
                            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.LoginPassword)%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            <%= Html.PasswordFor(model => model.LoginPassword)%>
                            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LoginPassword)%>
                        </div>
                    </li><li>
                        <div class="checkbox">                
                            <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Remember)%>
                            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Remember)%>
                        </div>
                    </li><li>
                        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Login" id="btnLoginSubmit" />
                        <div id="divlogin_ajaxloading" style="display:none; vertical-align:top; text-align:center;"><img alt="" src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
            }
```

your partial view action:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.LoginEmail, model.LoginPassword))
                {
                    return Redirect("/MyPage");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    return PartialView("LoginPopup", new LoginModel());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This solution redirect to a new page. I think i'll use the solution of gnome. I'm supprised there isn't a more simple solution in MVC2 to do that without changing page.

Comment: no it don't redirect to new page, if you are using strongly typed partial view with ajax.actionlink(), then in Create() return the result to partial view which in result re-generate the partial view only even doing post ... [it'll give you the same result as you achieve using JSON] ...

Comment: @dvlpr And where is displayed the partial view?

Comment: here you can see I am using Ajax.BeginForm(), which triggered when submit button clicked, and according to this if authentication is success then redirect it to user's homepage else clear ModelState and also re-initialize the LoginModel. And in the same manner you can use Ajax.ActionLink()

Comment: @dvlpr When I click on the Submit button in the Product's partialview, it's the Create's method of package which is called, not the Create's method of product :-/

Answer (score 1):

Just typed this up, haven't tested it but the basic idea is to list your products on the customer view with a button to add a new product for a customer.

To list Products for Customer:

```
<table>
    <% foreach(var p in Customer.Products) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%: p.Quantity %></td>
        <td><%: p.Name %></td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
<p><%: Html.ActionLink("Add Product", "Create", new { controller = 'Products' }, new { id = 'addProduct'}) %>

<div id="dialog"></div>
```

To add a new Product for a customer you could use jQuery UI to show a dialog; just pass the Customer Id

// assuming you've included jquery-ui

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog({ 
        autoOpen : false,
        button : { 
            'Save' : function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url : $('#addProduct').attr('href'),
                    type : 'get'
                    success : function() { 
                        alert('Product added!');
                    }
                });
            }, 
            'Cancel' : function() {
                $('#dialog').dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });

    $('#addProduct').click(function() {
        var customerId = $('#CustomerId').val();
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        $('#Customer_Product_Id').val(customerId); // assuming there's a hidden field on the form
    });
});
</script>
```

In your product controller return a partial

```
public ActionResult Create() 
{
    List<Product> products = new List<Product>() { 
        new Product() { Id = 1, Name = "Rice" },
        new Product() { Id = 2, Name = 'Corn' }};
    ViewData.Add("Products", new SelectList(products, "Id", "Name", ""));
    Product product = new Product();
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) 
    {
        return PartailView("_CreateOrEdit", product)
    }

    return View("Create", product);
}
```

_Create view

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Quantity) %>
<%: Html.DropDownList("Products") %>
<%: Html.HiddenFieldFor(model => model.Product.Customer.Id) %>
```

Comment: Thank for your code, it very interesting!
But, when I use it, the jQuery Dialog is visible 2 seconds then I'm redirected to Product/Create and display the partial view which should be in the dialog.

Comment: Oh... like I said, I didn't tease it out in visual studio. You need to include a return false; on the click event otherwise it will follow the link. I have a solution that does essentially want you need. Will see if I can dig it up for you; but it basically follows the above.

Comment: I have already tested with a 'return false;' but with that, the controller is never called and the partial view is never rendered...

Comment: Ok after using:             
    $('#dialog').load("/Product/Create");
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
I have what I want

Comment: Excellent. Happy programming!